# cron mutt email wildcard gz file

Tags: mysql, cron, email-attachments, mutt

I am using the following cron job to email my sites weekly mysql db backups but the date will keep changing. How do I wildcard the date so that the script will grab the correct site?

```
echo "Attached is the backup for SITENAME" | mutt -a "/html/automatic_backups/thenameofthedb_??-??-????_Sat.sql.gz" -s "SITENAME Weekly DB Backup" -- example@me.com
```

Each time the cron runs I want the script to look in the folder for x sites Sat.sql.gz file and email it to me.

Thank you in advice for your help and guidance.

Comment: Assuming you're emailing it remotely and not to a local user on the same server, are you encrypting the file first? Don't forget that email is visible to every server it passes through, all of which have the ability to store & forward outside your control. And unless it is encrypted, anyone with access to the MTAs it bounces through could get your data.

Comment: But for the file, maybe you could use something like `mutt -a "$(ls -1t /html/automatic_backups/thenameofthedb_*_Sat.sql.gz |head -n1)"` to retrieve the most recently modified backup file.  This would be more on topic over at http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com

Comment: It turns out that GoDaddy doesnt support the `mutt` function so it seems to be a dead issue but your point about the encryption issue prob would have been enough to convince me I need to find another solution. Thanks for your incite